# Randomized algorithm to determine if a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is irreducible

Tags: random, irreducible-polynomials

Is there an efficient (possibly randomized) algorithm to determine if a given polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[n]$ is irreducible?

Comment: You could simply factor it: unlike integer factorization, polynomial factorization can be done relatively quickly. (of course, a specialized irreducibility test will probably be faster, but factoring may be good enough for your purpose)

Comment: Theorem 9 of these notes (http://www.math.tamu.edu/~sue.geller/factoring.pdf) gives me an idea: try random linear changes of variables and look for a root. But it's not clear whether this will always work (can you always do a linear change of variables and get a polynomial with a linear factor, given that it was reducible to begin with?). Also, I don't really care too much about efficiency, so any $poly(n,p)$ time algorithm is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the algorithm that works, and it appears to be significantly faster than factoring. This comes from the Handbook of Applied Cryptography, whose notes can be found online here: http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/

[image]

Comment: For the record, this algorithm is essentially the same the second step in the most common algorithm for factoring over a finite field.

Comment: So contrary to your earlier comment, does "simply factoring it" require an irreducibility test? Or did you have another algorithm in mind that doesn't explicitly use such a test?

Comment: This test works because $x^{p^n} - x$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbf{F}_p$ whose degree divides $n$; so if $f(x)$ has any such factors, their product will be returned in $d(x)$. For factoring, running this algorithm to the end (and dividing off $d(x)$ each time it's nontrivial) gives you a partial factorization of $f(x)$, which gets fully factored in the third phase of the usual algorithm if it needs to be. For irreducibility testing, you can just stop as soon as you've found a nontrivial $d(x)$.